# Mysql multiple join query issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables to be join please see this three tables

composite_inventories
[image]

composite_has_inventories
[image]

inventories
[image]

above three table i have join using below query

```
SELECT u.id, u.purchase_item_name,u.sales_item_name, us.type ,Group_concat(s.itemcode) as Items FROM composite_inventories as u LEFT JOIN composite_has_inventories as us ON u.id = us.composite_inventory_id LEFT JOIN inventories as s ON US.inventory_id = s.id GROUP BY us.composite_inventory_id,us.type
```

I got output of my above query as below

[image]

but instead of above output i need output should be like this

```
 id | Purchase_item_name | sales_item_name | purchase_items   | sales_items
  -------------+-------+-----------+----------------------------
   12  | golden          | NULL             | A123,Z523,QQ5252 | NULL
   13  | test            | demoabc          | Z523,QQ5252      | Z523
```

please help me to convert this query to laravel query.

Comment: Have a try at `GROUP_CONCAT` and tell us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want it's necessary to join to the inventories table twice, once for purchases and once for sales. Then you can do a `GROUP_CONCAT` on the items from each of those `JOIN`ed tables to get `purchase_items` and `sales_items`.

This query should give you the desired result ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99adf4/5))

```
SELECT u.id, u.purchase_item_name,u.sales_item_name, us.type,
GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) AS purchase_items,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items 
FROM composite_inventories as u 
LEFT JOIN composite_has_inventories as us ON u.id = us.composite_inventory_id 
LEFT JOIN inventories as s ON US.inventory_id = s.id AND us.type='sale'
LEFT JOIN inventories as p ON US.inventory_id = p.id AND us.type='purchase'
GROUP BY u.id
```

Output:

```
id  purchase_item_name  sales_item_name     type        purchase_items      sales_items
12  golden              (null)              purchase    Z523,QQ5252,A123    (null)
13  test                demoabc             purchase    Z523,QQ5252         Z523
```